# fragment activity does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments

this is my code for the fragment there is no error put when it doesn't work !
each fragment have voice recognition button ,inputText which receive text ,and given text to make comparison with the inputText and highlight it Red if it is not match ..,

```
public class LayoutOne extends Fragment {

protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private TextView inputText;
    private TextView givenText;

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    LayoutOne f = new LayoutOne();  

    return f;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.layout_one);

    inputText = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    givenText = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.givenText);
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
            try{
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                inputText.setText("");
            }catch(ActivityNotFoundException a) { 

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_SPEECH: {
        if (resultCode == -1 && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            inputText.setText(text.get(0));
            if(givenText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(inputText.getText().toString())){

                inputText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("BLUE"));
            }
            else{

                {inputText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("RED"));}
            }
        }
        break;
       }
     } 
   }
 }
```

any Idea ?

Comment: Do you have a logcat error stacktrace? Try putting in some Log.v("Test","test") around your code and see what information you can make from that.

Comment: Also, post the activity that your fragment is inflated by. This is merely a fragment, not a fragmentactivity. You do not inflate this fragment anywhere in the code I can see

Comment: for readability: `resultCode == -1` should better be `resultCode == RESULT_OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create your fragment class differently as you do not have an inflater, a fragment doesn't use the generic onCreate as other android classes...

```
Public class myFragment extends Fragment{

TextView testTextView;
View myFragmentView
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle SavedInstantState) {

        myFragmentView = viewInflation.inflate(
                R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
            testTextView = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.testTextView);
   }
}
```

That is a basic example of how your fragment should be set up.... then you can inflate it in a `FragmentActivity` using a transaction manager and creating a field of your Fragment's class.

**[update]**

Also, if you use eclipse's visual editor you can just drag and drop a fragment from the visual menu and it should just ask you what fragment class you want to attach to it.

Comment: Does this make sense @user3002753

Comment: thank you . Are there any other solution , so i can implement the comparison code in the same fragment ??

Comment: I am not following what you are asking?